# if-elsif without conditions not branching correctly in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

When I run the following code:

```
if  
  puts "A"  
elsif  
  puts "B"  
end
```

I get the output:

```
A
B
```

Why does it not warn or raise any errors? And why does it execute both branches?

Comment: You can run the program via `ruby --dump=parsetree weird.rb` to see how the parser interprets your code.

Comment: @Stefan today I learned :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> an if-elsif without conditions

Here's where you're wrong. The `puts` **are** the conditions. There are no bodies in that snippet, only the conditions.

Here's your code, properly formatted.

```
if puts "A"  
elsif puts "B"  
end
```

> And why it executes both branches?

`puts` returns nil, a falsey value. That's why it tries both branches. If this code had an `else`, it'd be executed too.

Answer (score 2):

In other words :

```
if # this is the condition :
    puts "A" # an expression which prints A and returns nil
# hence it's like "if false", try elsif ...
then
    puts 'passes in then'
elsif # this is another condition :
    puts "B" # puts prints B and returns nil
else # no condition satisfied, passes in else :
    puts 'in else'
end
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
A
B
in else
```